# Prevent eclipse from building the projects before run an Ant task

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, launch

I want to prevent the project from compiling when I run an Ant task, how is this done?

Eclipse build setting is not automatic but the build still remains running before any ant task be launched.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can turn off `"Build (if required) before launch"`

You have turned rebuild off for resource modification but I believe you haven't turned off `"Build (if required) before launch"`

Go to:

`Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching -> Build (if required) before launching`

On older versions of eclipse:

`Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Build (if required) before launching`

Answer (score 20):

In newer versions of Eclipse (I have Neon) the option has moved slightly to:

`Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching`

The checkbox is still named: `Build (if required) before launching`.